# jquery.validate error placement

Tags: jquery

My CSS knowledge is a bit limited.

Would like to highlight the label in left div when error occurs in right div

```
messages: { 
    userID: ""

}, 
errorElement: "span",     
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {         
    element.siblings("label").append(error);     
    },     
    highlight: function(element) {         
    $(element).parent().children("div.left label").addClass("error");    
    },     
    unhighlight: function(element) {         
    $(element).parent().children("div.left label").addClass("error");     
    } 


 <div class="left">
 <label for="userID">Username:</label> <br />
 </div>
<div class="right">    
<input  type="text" name="userID" id="userID" onkeyup="nospaces(this)" maxlength="15" onBlur="checkUID(this)" onKeyPress="hideWarning()">
</div>
```

Currently "nothing" happens, no error, no highlight.  I'm unsure how to modify the errorPlacement script to comply.  Thx so very mch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all labels to be highlighted with the error class, use the setDefaults() function:

```
if ( jQuery.validator ) {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        /* Place error labels below invalid fields */
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            $('label[for=' + element.attr('id') + ']').addClass("error");
        }
    });
}

$('#commentForm').validate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/dvyqN/1/

Comment: Oy, i'm obviously not used to this forum.... I didn't see your comment, this will work.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(element).siblings("label").addClass("error");
```

to

```
$(element).parent().children("div.left label[for='password']").addClass("error");
```

This will select the label when it is in the left div.  Do the same for `.removeClass()`.  Finally, you can also be less specific with the selector and simply use `div.left label` instead of `div.left label[for='password']` if you want the rule to apply generally to all fields.

Comment: No Problem.  Also, make sure to close your `<label>` tag.  I noticed when I was editing your question that it wasn't closed before the `<br>` tag.  And if my answer fixes the issue, mark it answered. :)

Comment: jtfairbank, can you take another look at this?  Sorry, I thought I had added the left div in, however I was looking at the earlier version.  I'll edit the code above